# Problem while using CTFontRef in a loop to create NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: iphone, ipad, crash, core-text

I need to create a NSMutableAttributedString with different CTFontRef and CTParagraphStyleRef for different range in that string.

I try creating it by putting the following code in a loop and change range as I need,

```
CTFontRef normalFontRef = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)@"CourierNewPSMT", fontsize, NULL);
NSDictionary* normalFontAttribute = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:(id)normalFontRef,(NSString*)kCTFontAttributeName, nil];
[attributedString addAttributes:normalFontAttribute range:range];

CFRelease(normalFontRef);
[normalFontAttribute release];
normalFontAttribute = nil;

CTParagraphStyleRef paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(theSettings, theNumberOfSettings);
NSDictionary* paragraphAttribute = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:(id)paragraphStyle,(NSString*)kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName, nil];
[attributedString addAttributes:paragraphAttribute range:range];

CFRelease(paragraphStyle);
paragraphAttribute release];
paragraphAttribute = nil;
```

**My Problem is:**

The App crashes in device after some iteration of loop with out showing any details.
Just close the app no crash report, no message in console, no gdb break point.

**More Explanations:**
I call this NSMutableAttributedString creation method in another loop for some other processing, That loop is the crashed loop, not the NSMutableAttributedString creation loop. But if I commented calling the above method and use create a NSMutableAttributedString it works fine, see below

```
//works fine
attributtedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:stringContent];

//not working 
attributtedString   = [self createattributtedString:stringContent];
//this createattributtedString: method contain the first listed code
```

thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you running this in a device running iOS 3.1.xx - this is only available on 3.2 and above?

Comment: @deanWombourne, I worked in iOS4.2.2 and 4.3.1

Comment: How many times are you going through the look - perhaps it's a memory issue?

Comment: Arent you supposed to return the attributedstring? would be nice to see more code here..

Comment: @Fossli in that createattributtedString function I set attributes to the parameter string and finally return.

Answer (score 0):

You might have an endless loop.

Comment: This memory leaks find only in device debug and not leads to crash. But it shows Memory leaks waring in console. And it happens when the string content is large.

Comment: Well. It might be reason for his problem.