# Memory Leaks when calling some CTFunctions in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, core-graphics, core-text

I write a function to calculate the end index of attributtedString in a rect,

But it seems some memory leak,
Please help me to fix it.

```
CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)attributtedString);

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, rect);

CTFrameRef frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(currentIndex, 0), path, NULL);

CFRange frameRange = CTFrameGetVisibleStringRange(frame);
endIndex += frameRange.length;

CFRelease(frame);
CFRelease(path);
CFRelease(framesetter);
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: on a device or on the simulator? If it's on the simulator, test again on a real device; the simulator sometimes gives false readings.

Comment: @deanWombourne. I check in simulator and Activity Monitor it shows real memory is increasing. and When I check it in device the process end without any message.

Comment: Then I think your problem is that it doesn't work on a device - Id worry about the memory usage later!

Comment: @deanWombourne. ya It not work in device. my exact need is to create a NSAttributtedString see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345780/problem-while-using-ctfontref-in-a-loop-to-create-nsmutableattributedstring

Comment: @deanWombourne, I found that it works fine when I put it as IPA on device. while on device debug it still show memory leaks and cause crash

Comment: You have two options. (1) Ignore it, only use adhoc builds to test on the device. (2) Post more details about the crash so we can help you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no memory leak in the above example. As far as we can see you are releasing everything properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special release for CGPathRef objects.

```
//CFRelease(path);
CGPathRelease(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some more investigation on a device and there does seem to be a leak in CoreText, see [Memory usage grows with CTFontCreateWithName and CTFramesetterRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491841/memory-usage-grows-with-ctfontcreatewithname-and-ctframesetterref/17248890#17248890)